# unspecified pixel format in FFMPEG after creating MP4 file

Tags: c++, video-streaming, mp4, libavcodec, libavformat

I working on the project, To change the Codec and stream information of mp4 file. after the change the codec and stream information using this code, to vaildate the output file using av_dump_format() it shows exactly what i set in file.

```
AVCodecParameters *Out_codecpar=avcodec_parameters_alloc();
                Out_codecpar->codec_type=in_codecpar->codec_type;
                Out_codecpar->codec_id=AV_CODEC_ID_H264;
                Out_codecpar->codec_tag=in_codecpar->codec_tag;
                Out_codecpar->extradata=in_codecpar->extradata;
                Out_codecpar->extradata_size=in_codecpar->extradata_size;
                Out_codecpar->format=AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
                Out_codecpar->bit_rate=in_codecpar->bit_rate;
                Out_codecpar->bits_per_coded_sample=in_codecpar->bits_per_coded_sample;
                Out_codecpar->bits_per_raw_sample=in_codecpar->bits_per_raw_sample;
                Out_codecpar->profile=100;
                Out_codecpar->level=6;
                Out_codecpar->width=in_codecpar->width;
                Out_codecpar->height=in_codecpar->height;
                Out_codecpar->sample_aspect_ratio=in_codecpar->sample_aspect_ratio;
                Out_codecpar->field_order=in_codecpar->field_order;
                Out_codecpar->color_range=0;
                Out_codecpar->color_primaries=in_codecpar->color_primaries;
                Out_codecpar->color_trc=in_codecpar->color_trc;
                Out_codecpar->color_space=in_codecpar->color_space;
                Out_codecpar->chroma_location=in_codecpar->chroma_location;
                Out_codecpar->video_delay=in_codecpar->video_delay;
                Out_codecpar->channel_layout=in_codecpar->channel_layout;
                Out_codecpar->channels=in_codecpar->channels;
                Out_codecpar->sample_rate=in_codecpar->sample_rate;
                Out_codecpar->block_align=in_codecpar->block_align;
                Out_codecpar->frame_size=in_codecpar->frame_size;
                Out_codecpar->initial_padding=in_codecpar->initial_padding;
                Out_codecpar->trailing_padding=in_codecpar->trailing_padding;
                Out_codecpar->seek_preroll=in_codecpar->seek_preroll;
                ret = avcodec_parameters_copy(out_stream->codecpar, Out_codecpar);
```

after run output file in terminal using FFMPEG. it shows error like:

**Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none, 1280x720, 6194 kb/s): unspecified pixel format
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options**

This time i never messed up with any header information of mp4 file, and also i set Pixel format using **format=AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P**, why file is not play in VLC and how to pixel format for AV_CODEC_ID_H264?